# How to make camera relative movement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm learning unity and c#, and want to make my movement to be camera relative movement instead of world relative movement. How do I do that?

I'm learning unity and c#, my unity version is 2018.3.12f1. I would be happy for help.

just to let know, instead of moving the cam I'm rotating the player.

```cs
    void Update()
    {

     float AxisY = Player.transform.eulerAngles.y;  
    /* Movement starts here */

     Vector3 Movement = new Vector3 (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));

     if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightShift)) { //running code
        Player.transform.position += Movement * running_speed * Time.deltaTime;
     } else {
        Player.transform.position += Movement * speed * Time.deltaTime;
     }

     /*Movement ends here */

     /* Rotation controller starts here */

     Quaternion target = Quaternion.Euler(Player.transform.eulerAngles.x, Player.transform.eulerAngles.y, Player.transform.eulerAngles.z);

      /*if (Player.transform.eulerAngles.x != 0 || Player.transform.eulerAngles.z != 0 || Player.transform.eulerAngles.y != 0) {
               Player.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0,0,0);
         }*/

      if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E))
         {
            Debug.Log("E got pressed");
            //float AxisYPositive = Player.transform.eulerAngles.y;
            AxisY = AxisY+1;
            Player.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, AxisY, 0);

         } else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q)) 
         {
            Debug.Log("Q got pressed");
            //float AxisYNegetive = Player.transform.eulerAngles.y;
            AxisY=AxisY-1;
            Player.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, AxisY, 0);
         } 
    }
}
```

The player's movement is world relative, how to make the movement camera relative?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the movements relative to the `gameObject`, call the method `Transform.Rotate()` on the transform of the `gameObject` you want to rotate rather than modifying its `Quaternion` directly. Just make sure the final argument is set to `Space.Self`.

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E))
     {
        Debug.Log("E got pressed");
        //float AxisYPositive = Player.transform.eulerAngles.y;
        AxisY = AxisY+1;
        Player.transform.Rotate(Quaternion.Euler(0, AxisY, 0), Space.Self);
     }
```

Comment: How? (as I said I'm a newbie in c# and unity scripting)

Answer (score 0):

In general you don't want to directly mess with objects transform.rotation, at least not unless you at least somewhat understand quaternions (I don't!).

I can see a few issues with your code, but the common thread seems to be that you don't really understand how transforms work. Specifically, you might want to look into World/Local space.

The usual way to control a player goes roughly like this:

```
void DoMovement(Transform player)
{
  //If you move first your controls might feel 'drifty', especially at low FPS.
  Turn(player);
  Move(player);
}

void Turn(Transform player)
{
  float yaw = Input.GetAxis("Yaw") * time.deltaTime; //Aka turn left/right
  player.Rotate(0, yaw, 0, Space.Self); 
  // Space.Self is the default value, but I put it here for clarity.
  //That means the player will rotate relative to themselves, 
  //...instead of relative to the world-axis, like in your code.
}
```

You didn't ask about movement, but as-is your character will always move relative to the world. The below should make it move relative to the camera.

```
Transform _cameraTransform; //Assumes this is set druing Start()

void Move(Transform player)
{
  var forwardMove = _cameraTransform.Forward; //Get whatever direction is 'forward' for camera
  forwardMove.Y = 0; //Don't want movement up and down. 
  forwardMove = forwardMove.normalized; //Normalize sets the 'power' of the vector to 1.
  //If you set Y to 0 and don't normalize you'll go slower when camera looks down 
  //...than when camera is flat along the plane

  player.position += forwardMove * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * time.deltaTime;

  //Here you could do the same for strafe/side to side movement.
  //Would be same as above, but using the transform.right and Horizontal axis
}
```

Now, I'm making some assumptions here since you haven't specified what kind of game it is and what kind of controls you want. I'm assuming you have a character running around on a mostly flat plane (no aircraft/spaceship controls), and that the camera is attached to the player. This might not not actually be the case.

In any case I advice you to check out the [tutorials](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials), especially the Roll-a-Ball tutorial which I have found is good for beginners to get a grasp on basic players controls that are not just world-relative. The other tutorials, too, are pretty good if you think they're interesting.

Aside from the official Unity tuts a *ton* of decent to amazing tutorials out there, including video tutorials, so for something like this you could just search for `<game type> tutorial` and pick whatever seems good to you. While getting started I advice you to avoid the shortest videos, as you will likely benefit greatly from explanation that only fits in longer videos. Of course, that doesn't mean you should pick the longest videos either.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone needs to move an object and don't care about colliders, you can use [transform.Translate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html) and assign to his second parameter **relativeTo** your camera (or any transform) to automatically calculate the translation relative to the object assigned.